# how can I export a C# application from Visual Studio 2012 to run in other computers?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, export

I just made my first C# application in Visual Studio 2012 and I want to export it in some way so other people could use it in they computers (including computers without Visual Studio 2012). How can I do it? I'm new at C# and I couldn't find anything that I could understand. Can someone explain or indicate some site with a good (and maybe didactic) explanation on how it works? I have only made C/C++ programs by now, and they I just needed the .exe file, but, based on what I could find, I need something else to send a C# program to others to use.
Sory for the bad English and thanks for those who help.

Comment: in the bin folder you will find .dll files in with the .exe. You will need those also.

Comment: VS2012 discontinued support of msi packages

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Right-click the project in VS 2012, and choose `Publish...` from the context menu. Publishing to a file lets you create an installer:

- Choose a location in the file system to which you would like to save the installer
- Click `[Finish]`
- Wait for the publishing operation to complete

A `Setup.exe` installer file will be created at the location that you have selected in the first step of the publish wizard. Share the installer with the people to whom you would like to give your application.

Comment: What If i wanted to make my app portable ?

Answer (score 2):

After building your project, you will find an EXE file in `bin\(Debug or Release)`

Comment: This is good but I would expect Visual Studio to have an option to save `exe` file directly to my desktop for example, rather than I myself browsing for it.

Answer (score 0):

You need any computer that wants to run it to be windows, and running the correct version of the .net framework. If it's a program that's created with VS2012, that'll be .net 2.0 to 4.5.2. After that, you need to find the location of your program, and you can just copy the debug folder that you are currently running from, and your program will work.

Answer (score 0):

Check also the .net framework that it is required in order for c# apps to run. You can find what framework your app is build in projext properties. If the target computer has an old os (XP) maybe the .net framework needs also to be installed