# "Could not find a part of the path" Error in new machine

Tags: c#, error-handling, installation

I have made a windows form application in VS2015 and created an installer for that by descriptions in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17236339/how-can-i-export-a-c-sharp-application-from-visual-studio-2012-to-run-in-other-c). The problem is when I install it on another machine I get the error shown in the picture below. I am almost new to VS but it seems the installer does not contain the directory and doesn't copy that to new machine. I have some pictures in my directory folder but they can't be found on the other PC and just in the point the application should load the pictures, this error pops up:

[image]

Comment: Sure you have access rights?

Comment: It looks like you are distributing your application with ClickOnce. If the pictures are not found, check their *Properties* in the Solution Explorer; specifically the *Build action* you have selected for them. Perhaps add that info to your question.